# PHP - Codeigniter Validation using json

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter, validation

I have a fields and every field have a validation. all validation are working.

But the problem is in my field that will upload file. Even though i already put an image file still it will validate that I must upload an image.

im using sweetalert to show the validation errors.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function saveproducts(){
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/products';   
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    //$config['file_name'] = $this->input->post('prod_name');

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Product Image','callback_rulesprodimage');

    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
        echo json_encode(validation_errors());
    }else{

        $products = array(
            'product_image' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
            'upload_data' => $this->upload->data(),
            );

        $this->CrudModel->insertproductdata($products);

        echo json_encode(1);
    }

}

public function rulesprodimage(){
    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        return true;
        }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('rulesprodimage', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
        }
    }else{
      // throw an error because nothing was uploaded
      $this->form_validation->set_message('rulesprodimage', "You must upload an image!");
      return false;
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="prod-submit">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Product Image <span id="required"> * </span></label>
<input type="file" name="userfile" class="form-control">
</div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#prod-submit').on('submit',function(e) { 

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'adminpage/saveproducts/',

    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){

      var result = JSON.parse(data); 
        if(result===1){ 
            console.log(result);
            document.location.href = base_url+"adminpage/products/"
        }
        else{
           swal({
                type: 'error',
                html: result,

              }).done();
        }
    },
    error:function(data){
    swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");

    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file doesn't go through ajax just like that, so $_FILES is empty and CI doesn't see. You can transport file without page reloading with FormData object. Read more on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload). Watch out also on browser compatibility, because this api works on modern browsers and ie10+.

I usually do this with jquery plugins. There are many. One of the most popular is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload , other for example: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: sorry for late reply. your suggestion in using jquery file upload it works and im playing with it. thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Use FormData instead of serialize to upload the file, although I do warn it doesn't work for IE9 and below, you can read more about FormData [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#prod-submit').on('submit',function(e) { 

// Create a new FormData with your form selector inside.   

var formdata = new FormData($('form')[0]); 

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'adminpage/saveproducts/',

    data:formdata,
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){

      var result = JSON.parse(data); 
        if(result===1){ 
            console.log(result);
            document.location.href = base_url+"adminpage/products/"
        }
        else{
           swal({
                type: 'error',
                html: result,

              }).done();
        }
    },
    error:function(data){
    swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");

    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```